# How to extract the next x elements using an expression in R

Tags: r, string

How can I extract the 7 or 8 elements from a string following an expression?
For example:

```
text <- "Hello World! My name is Sam!"
expression <- "World!"
```

How to extract the expression + the next x elements(say 8)? So the results look like this:

```
 result <- "World! My name"
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use substring. Here you have to use `expression<- substring(text,7,12)
result <- substring(text,7,20)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R method with `sub`

```
sub(paste0(".*(", expression, ".{8}).*"), "\\1", text)
[1] "World! My name"
```

`paste0(".*(", expression, ".{8}).*")` returns the regex ".*(World!.{8}).*" where

".*" matches one or more characters of any type, "()" are capturing parentheses, "World!" is a literal, and ".{8}" matches the next 8 characters.

As @mt1022 notes in the comments, we can use another set of regex functions `regmatches` and `regexpr` to perform the extraction of the substring.

```
regmatches(text, regexpr(paste0(expression, '.{8}'), text))
[1] "World! My name"
```

`regexpr` returns indices of the substrings that match the expression and `regmatches` extracts these substrings from the character vector.

Comment: A similar one: `regmatches(text, regexpr(paste0(expression, '.{8}'), text))`

Comment: Nice solution, I should really start learning regular expressions. +1

Comment: @Florian If you work with text a lot, time invested in learning regex is well worth it and it is supported across many languages (and text editors).

Answer (score 1):

```
text <- "Hello World! My name is Sam!"
expression <- "World!"
n=8

ind = unlist(gregexpr(pattern =expression,text))[1]
substr(text,ind,ind+nchar(expression)+n-1)
```

where n is the number of additional characters. It returns:

```
"World! My name"
```

Hope this helps!